# linux shell: sed replace value in xml

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I have a xml file, I want to repace the text value in the tag < jdbcurl > with another value, but there are two tags named with jdbcurl nested in different pool id.

Can any one  do me a favor to dig it with SED?
Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
  <WEBServer fileName="webdb.xml" name="Configuration and Security File">
  <security>
  <pool id="DEFAULT" jndiName="jdbc/webdb">
     <dbschema></dbschema>
     <userID>DBUSER</userID>
     <password>passwd1</password>
     <jdbcdriver>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</jdbcdriver>
     <jdbcurl>jdbc:oracle:thin:@db.server.com:1753/ORCSN</jdbcurl>
  </pool>
   <pool id="bi_id" jndiName="jdbc/bidb">
    <dbschema></dbschema>
    <userID>BIUSER</userID>
    <password>passwd2</password>
    <jdbcdriver>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</jdbcdriver>
    <jdbcurl>jdbc:oracle:thin:@db.server.com:1753/ORCSN</jdbcurl>
  </pool>
 </security>
 </WEBServer>
```

Comment: I suggest to use xmlstarlet.

Comment: elaborate what `< jdbcurl >` value should be replaced. Should it depend on `pool id` or what?

Comment: Two words: Don't. [Don't.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -E '/bi_id/,/pool/  s/jdbc:[^<]*/you will replace/g' filename
```

this one will replace jdbc in pool with id='bi_id'

```
sed -E '/DEFAULT/,/pool/  s/jdbc:[^<]*/you will replace/g'
```

this is for DEFAULT pool's jdbcurl

Answer (score 1):

With xmlstarlet:

```
xmlstarlet edit --update '//WEBServer/security/pool[@id="DEFAULT"]/jdbcurl' --value 'XYZ' file.xml
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<WEBServer fileName="webdb.xml" name="Configuration and Security File">
  <security>
    <pool id="DEFAULT" jndiName="jdbc/webdb">
      <dbschema/>
      <userID>DBUSER</userID>
      <password>passwd1</password>
      <jdbcdriver>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</jdbcdriver>
      <jdbcurl>XYZ</jdbcurl>
    </pool>
    <pool id="bi_id" jndiName="jdbc/bidb">
      <dbschema/>
      <userID>BIUSER</userID>
      <password>passwd2</password>
      <jdbcdriver>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</jdbcdriver>
      <jdbcurl>jdbc:oracle:thin:@db.server.com:1753/ORCSN</jdbcurl>
    </pool>
  </security>
</WEBServer>
```

Comment: Thanks Cyrus. The xmlstarlet script looks clear and easy to understand.